# Should my speedlite burn through batteries when not in use?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, maintenance

I got a Canon Speedlite 430 EX II just a couple of weeks ago and noticed a surprising and annoying feature: If I leave batteries in the flash unit, even with the flash switched off and removed from the camera, the batteries will be dead in a day or two.

This happened to my twice with the expensive Energizer Advanced lithium batteries, so needless to say I was unhappy. But most devices I can leave the batteries in, and it won't drain much as long as the power is off. Is it something I am doing? Or perhaps there is something is wrong? What would be draining the batteries in this case, and is it normal?

Comment: You seem to imply you leave the flash attached to the camera, if so try leaving the batteries in but removing the flash from the camera.

Comment: I think you need another 430 EX II user to get a good answer, but with the myriad of flashes I've used from different manufacturers, no this isn't normal.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that--the flash is stored separately in the soft case it comes in.

Comment: Did you try using different batteries? Try finding SANYO Eneloop batteries or any other rechargeables.

Comment: I've used both standard off-brand AA alkalines as well as the Energizers mentioned above

Comment: This could be faulty flash unit, the only workaround is to use rechargeable batteries, take them out of the unit when not used, and charge the batteries every time you go out shooting. This is the process I actually use. I never leave batteries inside my flash unit.

Comment: Also, the flash unit should still be under warranty if you are unable to exchange it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a 580EX speedlight, and the *rechargeable* batteries can stay in there for months no problem. The flash unit can be turned on and ready to fire within seconds.
Of course there will be some battery drain, but 3 days is def. a sign of a problem.
You should seek a replacement if the problem persists.

Comment: Amazon authorized the exchange without issue. I will receive it on Tuesday and give it a shot.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up for posterity--I received the replacement unit early last July and the difference in battery use was immediately apparent. I've been happily using the 430 EX II since July with NiMH's. I get great cycle times and I'm happy with how long they last.